# Emacs' titlebar and dialogs theme is not matching Mac OS general settings

Tags: osx, mac

Before starting, I'm on Mac OS Monterey (12.2.1) with M1 chip. My Emacs' version is 27.2.

I made a change to let Emacs accessing my entire disk because it can't by default.

I followed [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/12/12/fixing-emacs-macos-catalina/) which worked because now Emacs can open any file from any folder.

But, I noticed something I want to get ride of :
[image: Emacs light theme demo]

Even though I restarted Emacs, it switched to light theme whereas my Mac OS settings are supposed to make it dark :
[image: Mac OS general settings]

I want to know if there is a workaround to make Emacs' back to dark theme AND still opening any file from any folder.

Answer (score 1):

So, after many and many search, I realized I was searching basing myself about Emacs, because I taught it only could happened to it, but it seems many other apps can run through this on Mac.

I type this command on prompt :

`defaults write org.gnu.Emacs NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool no`

Thanks to [this SoF question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/can-i-turn-to-dark-mode-only-for-specific-apps-in-macos-mojave)